# Trying to direct variable contents into command gives Ambigious Redirect

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, mail-command

I'm trying to write a script which tests the http response from various Node servers I have running and which then emails me if any respond with a 502 error from Nginx (meaning one or more server has crashed).

My approach is to write a shell-script and have it run as a cron job, and I'm using ssmtp to send the message through Gmail. Here is a snippet:

```
messageTemplate=`cat /home/sites/mailmsg.txt`
...
email="$messageTemplate One or more sites is down!"
mailCommand=`mail -s info@redearmedia.ca < $email`
```

I'm able to get the contents of the ssmtp mailer template (To:, From:, etc.) with no issues. And I'm sure the email line concatenates just fine. The problem is that the mailCommand line fails with the line:

`line 31: $email: ambiguous redirect`

What is the proper way to pipe what is essentially that messageTemplate + a custom message into the first command (in this case, `mail`)?

Comment: In general if you have such problems then you should create a working command line.

Comment: You mean recreate it by running the `mail` command with all of the options and contents of the variable extracted? I suppose that makes good sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My crystal ball thinks that maybe your message text contains one of more of `<` or `>`.

It looks to me like your usage

```
mailCommand=`mail -s info@redearmedia.ca < $email`
```

will not do what you want: this will take the content of `$email` as a filename (failing somewhat because `$email` consists of several words), try to read its contents, pu tthose into the `mail` command, and then assign the output of the `mail` command to the variable `mailCommand`.

My thinking would be that you want something like

```
echo "$email" | mail -s info@redearmedia.ca
```

i.e. take the string in the variable `email` and feed it to the mail program?

(As a side note, many people nowadays prefer the notation `$(foo)` for command substitution, instead of backticks.)

Comment: Well explained, thank you. Your proposed solution worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
messageTemplate=`cat /home/sites/mailmsg.txt`
...
mailCommand=`echo "$messageTemplate One or more sites is down"\! | mail -s info@redearmedia.ca`
```

or

```
email="$messageTemplate One or more sites is down"\!
mailCommand=`echo "$email" | mail -s info@redearmedia.ca`
```

Comment: Thank you - this could be the correct answer as it did solve my issue, but @Ulrich Schwarz did the same and gave a good explanation as to why it wasn't working as intended. +1 for proposing a working solution.